# c# Regex - Only get numbers and whitespaces in one string and only text and whitespaces in another

Tags: c#, regex

How do I only get numbers and include whitespaces in one string and only text and white spaces in another?

Iv'e tried this:

```cs
string value1 = "123 45 New York";
string result1 = Regex.Match(value1, @"^[\w\s]*$").Value;

string value2 = "123 45 New York";
string result2 = Regex.Match(value2, @"^[\w\s]*$").Value;
```

result1 need to be "123 45"

result2 need to be " New York"

Comment: Try something like `Regex.Split(s, @"(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)")` if you need to tokenize a string into whitespace-separated digit chunks and the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
        string value1 = "123 45 New York";
        string digitsAndSpaces = Regex.Match(value1, @"([0-9 ]+)").Value;

        string value2 = "123 45 New York";
        string lettersAndSpaces = Regex.Match(value2, @"([A-Za-z ])+([A-Za-z ]+)").Value;
```

Update:

> How do I allow charachters like å ä ö in result from value2?

```
        string value3 = "å ä ö";
        string speclettersAndSpaces = Regex.Match(value3, @"([a-zÀ-ÿ ])+([a-zÀ-ÿ ]+)").Value;
```

Comment: How do I allow charachters like å ä ö in result from value2?

Comment: Regex.Match(value3, @"([a-zÀ-ÿ ])+([a-zÀ-ÿ ]+)").Value;

Comment: Your digitsAndSpacess breaks in the following case: `092-39908`.

Answer (score 0):

The fallowing regex will allow only digits and spaces between them, the same goes with characters.

**Regex**: `(?:\d[0-9 ]*\d)|(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z ]*[A-Za-z])`

**Details**:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times
- `|` or

**Output**:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-6     `123 45`

Match 2
Full match  7-15    `New York`
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kqzo0M/2)